# why is my featured image from each page not displaying in my menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, themes

First time onstructing a wordpress theme and im trying to group a list of pages to display in on the front page ive added featured images into the themes support and all the pages and menus are set correctly with featured image.

This is the code to display the menu i want it to display the name and the featured image of the page

```
<div class="row">
  <?php
        $navMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items(products); /*/Pass Nav Menu_id or Name*/
        foreach ($navMenu as $menu) {
if($menu->menu_item_parent == 0)
            {
                echo '<div class="col-md-4"><a href="'. $menu->url .'">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($menu->ID) . '<p>' . $menu->title . '</p></a></div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

the names of the pages in the menu are showing with their links but the featured image is not appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($menu->ID)
```

Because `$menu->ID` is id of the menu item, not the post/page/category where it is pointing to.

I think you're looking for `object_id:`

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($menu->object_id)
```